# Create a list with empty map

Tags: scala

I have a JSON string which is parsed and a typecaseted to a `map`. I'm using this map to get a `List[Map[String, Any]]`. Here to make my code error free I have used `getOrElse` while type casting.

JSON string looks similar to

```
{
  "map-key" : [
     {
       "list-object-1-key" : "list-object-1-value"
     },
     {
       "list-object-2-key" : "list-object-2-value"
     }, 
  ]
}
```

My code

```
val json = JSON.parseFull(string) match {
    case Some(e) =>
          val list = e.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
                  .getOrElse("map-key", List[Map[String,Any]]) // Error here
          val info = list.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]]
          //iterate over each element in the list and perform my operations
   case None => string
}
```

I can understand that whenever there is no result present in `list` object then `info` object is repeated code.

How can I improve this programme by giving the default value to `list` object?

Comment: Here's an empty `Map` of that type: `Map[String,Any]()` And here's an empty `List` of that type: `List[Map[String,Any]]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default value is wrong. You're passing a type, not an empty list.

```
e.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]].getOrElse("map-key", List.empty[Map[String,Any]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it in more functional way, without `asInstanceOf`:

```
    val parsed = JSON.parseFull(string)
    parsed match {
        case Some(e: Map[String, Any]) =>
            e.get("map-key") match {
                case Some(a: List[Any]) =>
                    a.foreach {
                        case inner: Map[String, Any] => println(inner.toList)
                    }
                case _ =>
            }
        case None => string
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i don't have the environment at this machine but try something like that

first thing you need to convert json to map

```
def jsonStrToMap(jsonStr: String): Map[String, Any] = {
  implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats

  parse(jsonStr).extract[Map[String, Any]]
}
```

and the second thing you will need to iterate over map to get values of list

```
val list= jsonStrToMap.map{ case(k,v) => (k.getBytes, v) }. toList
```